# Can I insert a file into the install disk?

Tags: system-installation, startup-disk-creator

I have some pdf support and how tos that I would like to end up on every install, is there a way of doing this from my usb startup disk? Or would I need to make a customer iso

Comment: You can do it if you enable persistence. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence